# What did the tanks fire at?

Tags: plot-explanation, super-8

Ok, I have a question about *Super 8*. In a scene toward the end, Donny lets Joe drive his car because he is too stoned. During the next scene we see a tank fire, along with other shots being fired/explosions.

My question is: What the hell are they shooting at? Isn't the alien underground? I know some military guy said something about misfiring... Is the alien causing all military devices to malfunction? How would the alien force the tanks to fire?

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). For multiple unrelated questions it's actually advisable to ask them each as separate individual questions to make them assessable and answerable individually. Your 1st and 2nd question seem completely unrelated to each other (and maybe also the 2nd and 3rd, not sure about that).

Comment: Since your question was garnering close-votes for being too broad (for the reason I described in my previous comment), I took the liberty to remove the 2nd and 3rd questions to make it a valid and answerable question. Feel free though, to ask the other questions as separate questions on their own (you can take a look at this question's [revision history](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/31750/revisions) if you need their wording).

Comment: @close-voters Feel free to rectract your vote now that the question has been repaired.

Comment: Huh, you're right, I've never thought about it like that. That's so weird, because the alien never comes out until the end when it makes its spaceship. What are they shooting at?? I'll have to watch it again

Comment: At some point, yes. The alien was indeed controlling the militaries weapons, but until I get another chance to rewatch it, I can't answer as to when it took control.

Answer (score 3):

From the [wiki](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Super_8_alien)

> The alien also has electromagnetic powers which can cause guidance systems to break down and make missiles misfire.

I believe that it was mentioned that the military weapons were misfiring. So the alien is indeed underground but is close enough to cause the military's weapons to malfunction.

Comment: I just watched the movie last night.  As the army is rolling into town and the guns start firing, there's a quick shot of a soldier on the radio saying something like "The weapons are misfiring, sarge.  All of them.  It's real bad."

Answer (score 0):

They don't know the alien is underground. The kids discover that after they drive back from the base. It's possible the army is shooting at the location where the alien was last sighted.